# Can new-age be considered an indie genre?

Tags: genre, indie

Can new-age be considered an indie genre?

Like [Enya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enya)—the genre of her music is considered new-age, but I do not see many differences in her music from indie music. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Indie:  noting or relating to independently produced music: indie rock

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indie)

> (of a pop group, record label, or film company) not belonging to or affiliated with a major record or film company.

[Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_enUS484US492&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=indie%20define)

According to these definitions and the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New-age_music#History), it seems like New Age can be put right on the edge of "indie".

Wikipedia says that New Age was "initially produced and sold only by independent labels," which implies that some New Age is produced/affiliated with major labels now.  My guess is that since it's still a relatively obscure genre, it is mostly produced by independent labels.